# Flat button in WPF - trigger not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, flat

I wanted to restyle my buttons to be more flat so I have created two styles; first for `ToggleButton` that derives from `ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey` and second for `Button`that derives from `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey`.

It worked great - the buttons are now toolbar-like and flat. Second thing I wanted is to have `Background` property to be transparent when user hovers the cursor over the control. So to achieve that I defined a simple trigger that sets the `Background` to `Transparent` on `IsMouseOver` event. It worked for `ToggleButton`, however, the same trigger didn't work for `Button`(the background was not affected at all).

Does anyone know why this trigger works great for `ToggleButton` and does not work for `Button`? I did expect the same behavior since both styles are from the same family.

Below is the full code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfButtonsTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="FlatToggleButton"  TargetType="ToggleButton" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}">
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="FlatButton"  TargetType="Button" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
  <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
 </Window.Resources>
 <Grid>
<StackPanel>
  <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource FlatToggleButton}">
    I am Toggle Button
  </ToggleButton>

  <Button Style="{StaticResource FlatButton}">
    I am Button
  </Button>
</StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look using Snoop (a very handy program for inspecting WPF ) and it looks like the template which you're using as a basis, `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey`, has a trigger which selects a solid `Brush` for the background of a `Border` element within the `Button` (in thise case when `IsMouseOver` is true).

Your local style trigger is successfully setting the background of the `Button` element to transparent (or rather, keeping it transparent), but the `Border` background is unaffected, so you'll still see the highlighting behaviour.

Border Background:
[image: Border Background]

Button Background:
[image: Button Background]

I think you'll have to define a `ControlTemplate` to get the button you're after, I've grabbed this from one of the `ToolBar` samples included in Kaxaml (a nice XAML editor). It's a reasonable facsimile of the `Toolbar` bas button style, with a few bits removed, it may behave as you want, or you might need to tweak it depending on your desired behaviour.

I've left the `IsPressed` trigger in place, you may want to remove it, or add additional triggers.

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarButtonBaseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <Border 
                    x:Name="Border"  
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        Margin="2"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- Additional triggers removed, e.g "IsMouseOver" -->
                    <!-- You may not want any at all -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#E0E0E0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#606060" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the both **FlatToggleButton** and **FlatButton** styles already have **Background** as **Transparent**

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
```

When the triggers is fired on **IsMouseOver** and set the **Background** again to **Transparent** you will not see any difference

So what you need to do is one of these options :

- **Change both styles** so that the **Background** is something else than  **Transparent**
- **Change the trigger** so it sets the **Background** to something else than **Transparent**

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. It doesn't matter what brush is used, the background is not changed at all (remains default on mouse hover).