# Wpf button background won't change from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background-color

I am using a custom `MenuButton` inherited from `Button` (without a xaml file):

```
    public class MenuButton : Button
    {
        public MenuButton()
        {
            base.Click += click;
            base.MouseLeave += mouseleave;
        }
        public MenuButton(string caption, ICommand command)
            : this()
        {
            SetValue(ContentProperty, caption);
            Caption = caption;
            Commando = command;
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            this.Style = FindResource("MenuButton") as Style;
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        public ICommand Commando;
        public string Caption;

        void mouseleave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (selected)
            {
                 SetValue(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Crimson);
            }
            else
            {
                SetValue(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent);
            }
        }

        bool selected = false;

        void click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuButtons menu = null;

                DependencyObject dep = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
                while (dep != null && !(dep is ItemsPresenter))
                {
                    dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
                }
                var a = dep as FrameworkElement;
                menu = a.DataContext as MenuButtons;

            foreach (var item in menu.MenuItems)
            {
                if (item == sender)
                {
                    SetValue(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White);
                    SetValue(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Crimson);
                    selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.SetValue(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
                    item.SetValue(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent);
                    item.selected = false;
                }
            }

            Commando.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

and I apply the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuButton"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type c:MenuButton}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock"
                Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="8" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="11" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                Value="Verdana" />
</Style>
```

This works, the ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey gives a nice blue/gray hover color.
In code behind I want to set foreground and background colors depending on each buttons "selected" status. In the event `void click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` I set these colors for all menuitems in an array (they are grouped in a usercontrol).

```
foreach (var item in menu.MenuItems)
{
    if (item == sender)
    {
        SetValue(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.White);
        SetValue(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Crimson);
        selected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        item.SetValue(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
        item.SetValue(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent);
        item.selected = false;
    }
}
```

Now the foreground color changes ok. But the background color is probably overridden by the `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` and it stays blue/gray! Only when I click on *another* `MenuButton`, the crimson color appears on the button *I just left*. It's just so strange that I cannot set the background properly, how could I fix this, without writing devilish ControlTemplates?

Comment: Can you tell me what the c:MenuButton class is? Is this a custom class you wrote? I'm trying to recreate your issue, if you could post the code for it that would be helpful.

Comment: Looking at the `foreach` statement you posted I see that in the else part you are doing `item.` and in the if part you are setting the values on the outer control because you don't do `item.` when calling `SetValue()`. Is this intentional? I wrote a simple example and replaced the if block to use `item.SetValue` and it appears to work fine.

Comment: In my code (I posted the MenuButton class), using item.SetValue instead of SetValue on itself doesn't make any difference, because item == this. Replacing sender with this is somewhat better code.

Comment: Btw: debugging shows that this.Background is set to Crimson, it just doesn't display.

Comment: The problem is due to the Button's internal animations overriding your colors when the states are changing. So even though you set your Background and Foreground the button changes them again because it is doing fancy animations. If you post more code I can get back to you with a solution. You will need to create a ControlTemplate for your button. I also suggest using a ToggleButton instead because it comes with the IsChecked property already.

Comment: @baueric: Thanks for your effort. I found another detail in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18646580/138078. Next I will change my control to radiobutton-datatemplate with a togglebutton-controltemplate as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19376462/138078.

Comment: It is still rather strange that setting the background influences the animation, like in "if (background == ..)"