# Which wpf control is best suited for this menu scenario?

Tags: wpf, menu, user-controls

I need a button-style menu, i.e. horizontally arranged group of always visible buttons.
Like radiobuttons they should have a *selected* property, i.e. the click-command should fire only when the *selected* status changes to true, not on every click as with a normal button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that a [ListBox with a horizontal layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1292585/138078) in a WrapPanel suits my scenario perfectly.
I posted the solution in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563425/typeconverter-from-string-to-usercontrol).

Answer (score 2):

Dude, this is WPF, you can use any control that fits some or any of your requirements and then simply provide a new `ControlTemplate` for it. Incidentally, there is no `Selected` or `IsSelected` property on a `RadioButton`... perhaps you were referring to the `IsChecked` property? This property is inherited from the `ToggleButton`, so that *may* be more appropriate.

As the `ToggleButton` is already a `Button`, you could even get away without providing a new `ControlTemplate` for it.

As for your requirement regarding the `Click` event, I don't think that you will find that functionality on any of the WPF controls, but it could be manually implemented:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ToggleButton.IsChecked == true) 
    {
        // Do something here when the `Button.IsChecked` == true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`RadioButton` also like other Buttons fire `Click` event on every click. Also there is no Selected property on the `RadioButton`.

But if you want your `MenuItems` to be like `Button`, then you can use `ToggleButton` here.
`ToggleButton` has `IsChecked` Property which tracks the checked state of button and `Checked` event which is fired when `ToggleButton` is Checked.

Also, if you want to automatically check/uncheck your ToggleButtons on click of other ToggleButton then you can use `RadioButton` as `DataTemplate` of your `MenuItem` and override its `Template` like below:

```
      <RadioButton Content="MyRadio" Click="RadioButton_Click">
            <RadioButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <ToggleButton Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </RadioButton.Template>
        </RadioButton>
```