# MVVM Datagrid to Observable Collection binding of generic types

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a xaml UserControl in which the DataContext refers to a "Control"-ViewModel.

```
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance controls:ControlViewModel}"
```

Furthermore, I´ve binded the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection which is generic from a "Data"-ViewModel. (Please Note: these data are only for demonstration)

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Visibility="{Binding AgeVisibility}"  Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

```
public class ControlViewModel
{
        private ObservableCollection<DataViewModel> _dataViewModels;
        public ObservableCollection<DataViewModel> DataViewModels
        {
            get { return _dataViewModels; }
            set
            {
                   _dataViewModels = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("DataViewModels");
            }
        }
}
```

The "Data"-ViewModel has the following Properties, which I´ve binded to the specific DataGridTextColumn (as you can see).

```
public class DataViewModel
{
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private int _age;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set
            {
                _age = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }

        private Visibility _ageVisibility;
        public Visibility AgeVisibility
        {
            get { return _ageVisibility; }
        }
}
```

Everything works, expect that the Visibilty Property of the "Age" Column doesn´t easily refer to the generic DataViewModel (Properties) of the Observable Collection such as the Binding Property. So it cannot be solved and it´s always on it´s default.

Comment: What is your question? Is it just that Resharper is complianing or is something not working?  If you are having a problem I would suggest you do away with the "AgeVisibility" property and use a value converter instead.  if you want to keep the property but don't want a setter then then add `RaisePropertyChanged("AgeVisibility")` to your `Age` setter and put the visibility logic calculation there.

Comment: @MatthewWhited The question is, how can i bind the Visibility Property to the AgeVisibility Property of the DataViewModel? My way doesn´t work, because it´s not binded to the generic type of the observable collection and therefore cannot be found. I´m setting the private field _ageVisibilty it in the ctor, so I don´t need a setter and even if I use one for it, it also doesn´t work.

Comment: when is AgeVisibility ever changed or set? Why you don't just make it a property like Age or Name, that way when you set it everything will work?

Comment: No, the binding is incorrect. It has not sth to do with a missing RaisePropertyChanged setter. It is not found, because I think the DataGridTextColumn Property "Binding" like Binding="{Binding Name}" refers to only one object of the ObservableCollection, so this is found by the generic => ObservableCollection<DataViewModel> DataViewModels. But the Property Visibility does not refer to it, so it isn´t found and ReSharper also warns for this: "cannot resolve property"...

Answer (score -1):

If you want a bindable property then add a second `RaisePropertyChanged` to the properties that control the readonly property.

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    //other stuff

    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Age");
            RaisePropertyChanged("AgeVisibility");
        }
    }

    public Visibility AgeVisibility
    {
        get { return this.Age > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden; }
    }
}
```

You can also use type converters like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19564006/89586)

Comment: The Property is also "bindable" with only a getter, because I "set" (the private field) it only once at constructor. The Problem is, that it cannot be resolved, see my answer above.

Comment: It should work fine.  Where are you setting the value of `_ageVisibility`.  At that time call the `RaisePropertyChanged(...)` method.  Resharper complaining doesn't mean XAML isn't working correctly.  Just as your broken implmentation doesn't make my answer wrong.

Comment: BTW where is your base class or at least the `INotifyPropertyChanged `

Comment: This is not the problem. I´ve found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074985/4367848

Comment: Okay... well that's a different issue then "ReSharper also warns that AgeVisiblity cannot be resolved"